# Subtract the mean array value from itself

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I need to calculate the scatter of some points and for that i need to calculate the mean of a 50x20 vector and subtract each its mean value by every row, like in this formula:

[image]

For such vector for instace:

```
my_vector = [3, 6, 5, 4, 2],
            [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            [4, 3, 2, 1, 5],
            [5, 3, 1, 3, 4],
```

All i am trying to figure out is how do i do in python the following:

```
        mean - [3, 6, 5, 4, 2],
        mean - [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        mean - [4, 3, 2, 1, 5],
        mean - [5, 3, 1, 3, 4],
```

Comment: What's the expected output for this data? a matrix of the same size, where each cell is the original value minus the mean of the row?

Comment: Try writing the code, even if it does it in an inefficient way using loops, and we can help you optimize it.  Don't just give us the entire problem statement and expect us to write the code from scratch.  Also, that example "vector" you gave is a matrix and is not written in valid Python syntax.

Comment: Are you talking about the mean of the row or the mean of the entire matrix?

Comment: Take the mean and subtract for every row, im new with python and here, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code calculates **mean row wise** & **subtract from matrix row wise** also.
I converted your **my_vector into matrix** for calculation.

```
import numpy as np
my_vector = ([3, 6, 5, 4, 2],
            [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            [4, 3, 2, 1, 5],
            [5, 3, 1, 3, 4])

my_matrix = np.array(my_vector)

#print(my_matrix)
mrow = np.mean(my_matrix,axis=1) #row mean
mrow = np.round(mrow)
print(mrow)
#print(my_matrix.shape[0])

d_meaned = my_matrix.copy()

for i in range(my_matrix.shape[0]):
    d_meaned[i] = d_meaned[i]-mrow[i]
print(d_meaned)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're looking for, here's a solution:

```
(a.transpose() - a.mean(axis=1)).transpose()
```

The output is:

```
array([[-1. ,  2. ,  1. ,  0. , -2. ],
       [-2. , -1. ,  0. ,  1. ,  2. ],
       [ 1. ,  0. , -1. , -2. ,  2. ],
       [ 1.8, -0.2, -2.2, -0.2,  0.8]])
```